# Dialect & Indigenous fonts if there (and usage on internet)

Tags: fonts, webfonts, truetype, fontforge

*How to start doing a indigenous font?* for example [Mexica writing](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escritura_mexica) but I think of others that could also have this characteristics:

- Different drawings for same sound say 4 ideograms for `a` (do I need to chose 1 of the 4 or make them all in which order?).
- Some of the sounds are like hiragana/katakana with vowels and consonants in a table.

Dont know if those 2 things does affect the way ones make a font for that writing.

So in **fontforge** how to design/develop such native font to be used by other people?

- if this indigenous language doesnt have a utf8 representation (as far as I know and it should happen in each country with their owns dialects or indigenous voices) how should I start just drawing in the places of a, b, c, d, e, f, ..., x, y, z?.
- how to use this font inside a page? or maybe inside a document application?.

Comment: It might help if you can provide more specifics about the language and script involved.

Comment: Mexica writing would be the first.

Answer (score 2):

Most writing systems for real human languages are represented in the Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). Unicode provides an *encoding* dictating which slots to place which characters in. Set this encoding in FontForge by Encoding > Reencode > ISO 10646-1 (Unicode, BMP).

In some cases you may need extra glyphs to provide a different appearance for certain characters in certain contexts. It is still the same unicode character with the same logical meaning, but in certain contexts it may require a different glyph. An example from the latin alphabet is that (depending on the font) you may need two "Q" glyphs, one with a shorter tail for use in situations where it is followed by a character with a descender. In other situations you may need to provide ligatures, which are special glyphs for two or more characters joined together. Unicode provides some slots purposely for ligatures and variant character forms, but others you may have to provide yourself. The ones you provide should usually be put in the "Private Use" block, uniE000 to uniF4FF. You can then create lookups to substitute these characters in appropriate circumstances: https://fontforge.org/lookups.html.
These lookups will be applied by most modern software, if you generate your font in OpenType format.

Right-to-left text should work automatically for characters in the appropriate unicode slots.

Making digital fonts is a highly technical business, especially if you want to get into the complexities of OpenType features such as ligatures and contextual substitutions. Not for the faint-hearted!